# change or add style to variables on tags?

Tags: html, jquery, styles

how can change style of variables on tags?

information :

```
 var $classi = $("#class").val();
 var $id = $("#id").val();
 var $value = $("#value").val();

$("#").append('<input class="default ' + $classi + '" type="text" id="' + $id + '" value="' + $value + '"' ');
```

i want addstyle to $value

```
$value.css('text-align','right') ;
```

is incorrect . because when i tried that . elements were not made . 
i want to change or add style values . 
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add styles to `$value` because `$value` is a value - `var $value = $("#value").val();` - and not a DOM element. You can add style to the element with the `id` value like this:

```
 $("#value").css("text-align", "right");
```

As your question is how to add styles to variables on tags - if you would declare `var $value = $("#value")` instead, the expression `$value.css("text-align", "right");` would work.

Comment: do you have any idea that how can i add style? 
look . we have some vars that makes with user's . like height  - background and etc ... i can set style some vars by adding span tag . 
but here i want to give chance to users that can choose input's value text-align . how can i?

Comment: @Alex Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/70c18a2u/1/

Comment: yes but. users may creates several inputs. i want the current input gets this style. no others .

Comment: and the style options is before creating . no after like editing somethings